# Crystal report designer not opening operation not found error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

My crystal reports were working fine until I decided to save as pdf and I was getting an error system path not found, after that I read somewhere that I can install the 32 bit version and it will work but the problem is after I installed the 32 bit version runtime file, my reports aren't opening when I double click on a crystal report to view it's designer I'm getting the error "operation not found"

I can view them when I run my application but I can't edit or change the designer! I'm seriously freaked out right now :( 
I can't even create a new crystal report, I get the exact same error.

I uninstalled the 32 bit version runtime file and reinstalled the 64 bit version runtime file but the error still prevails.
Should I uninstall everything and reinstall it or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by removing my previous installation and installing crystal reports all over again!